# Removing unwanted elements from tail of array?

Tags: matlab

I have an 100x1 array that starts with 100 zeros,

```
roots = zeros(100, 1);
```

I then have a loop in which an element this array gets filled on every iteration.

```
for iRoots = 1:100
    roots(iRoots) = a;
```

However if a certain condition is met the loop terminates early and I am left with a lot of unneccessary zeros in the array. For example I might be end up with a roots array like this:

```
charVals = [ 1  5  2  2  8 0 0 0 ... 0 ]
```

I only want to keep the first five non zero elements. How do I delete all the zeros from this array?

Comment: So if you only want the first five non-zero elements, can't you run the loop only from `1:5`, and initialize the array with `zeros(5,1)`?

Comment: This was just an example, it could turn out that there would be more or less than five elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the loop terminates early you will still have the value of the latest executed index, so just do:

```
roots(iRoots:end) = [];
```

Besides if you check for conditions to terminate a loop early, you might consider using a while loop instead of a for loop.